# How to get a CD out of MacBook disc drive

Tags: optical-drive

...the drive is 'whirring' etc, but not ejecting the cd.

I restarted and held down the mouse on the start-up chime -- that worked once; but I then put the cd back in and that method no longer works.

How do I get the cd out?

Thanks,